# mysql insert server_id while creating record in table

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have a table in mysql in which records can be created from different servers(servers are configured for master slave replication and server ids of each server has been set to 1, 2, 3 and so on), I wanted to know if there is some way by which I can set the default value of a column to server_id or @@server_id so that I can identify which server has created the record.

I have tried

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` 
ADD COLUMN `somecolumn` TINYINT NULL DEFAULT server_id
```

But the above one is not working.

Comment: "Not working" is not a helpful diagnostic. What error(s), if any, did you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` 
ADD `somecolumn` TINYINT NULL DEFAULT server_id
```

try it without `ADD COLUMN` and just use `ADD`